# Invoke clustering functions in R using Java

Tags: java, r

I am trying to cluster some data in R and I invoke the r functions from Java, using Renjin.

It all works fine to the calculation of the distance function:

```
 this.engine.eval("dis<-dist(myMatrix, \"binary\")");
```

However, when I try to do the actual clustering:

```
  this.engine.eval("clus<-hclust(dis)");
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: object 'C_hclust' not found
```

Google is not exactly elaborate on that point. Is it even possible to fix that or does clustering with renjin simply not work yet? 
I know renjin is still a bit experimental, but I thought clustering would, at least in R, be rather basic.

Comment: Similar errors, might help: http://packages.renjin.org/packages/birch.html

Comment: I ended up on a similar page before, but it seems to me only to be enlisting possible errors.